# change innerHTML of cocoa DOMElement

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

Objective-c, Webview

Hello, 
I'm trying to change the innerHTML of an DOM elemnent in a DOMDocument:

DOMDocument *myDOM = [[storyDisplay mainFrame] DOMDocument];
DOMElement *heading = [myDOM getElementById:@"heading"];
[heading setNodeValue:@"hejsa"];

Nothing seems to change when the above lines are executed, is this the right way to edit the innerHTML attribute?

Thanks,
Mads Hartmann Jensen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the -setInnerHTML: method?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that one way to achieve this was to use Javascript to play around with the DOM:

```
id *scriptObject= [storyDisplay windowScriptObject]; 
[scriptObject callWebScriptMethod:@"repleaceHeader" withArguments:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Whatever you want the header to be"]];
```

This bit of code gets the scripting environment from the webview and executes a javascript function by the name 'replaceHeader' with and array of argument (in my case only a string).

This require that you have a javascript function with that name, part of my html document looks like this:

```
<h1 id="heading">Welcome to Cookie</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
function repleaceHeader(header) { 
    var heading = document.getElementById("heading"); 
    heading.innerHTML = header; 
}       
</script>
```

Comment: this works, and is **fierce**.  i actually read about it elsewhere...  but it's like COMET and JQUERY rolled into one... You just push your sh*t onto the DOM, brute force.  No requesting, no responding...  just DOING.